# Soundcloud API Stream different songs

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

I'm trying to create a simple javascript soundcloud player, based on the trackid that I pass via onclick function.

This is my html:

```
<div id="gs-play" onclick="play(309689093, this.id)" class="fa fa-3x fa-play">play/pause</div>
<div id="gs-play2" onclick="play(316017522, this.id)" class="fa fa-3x fa-play">play/pause</div>
<div id="gs-play3" onclick="play(315363199, this.id)" class="fa fa-3x fa-play">play/pause</div>
```

And this is my javascript:

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: 'CLIENT_ID'
});
var is_playing = false,
    sound;
function play(trackid, id){
    var id = id;
    var url = '/tracks/' + trackid;

    if( sound ) {
        if(is_playing) {
            sound.pause();
            document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle('fa-pause');
            is_playing = false;
        } else {
            sound.play();
            document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle('fa-pause');
            is_playing = true;
        }
    } else {
        SC.stream(url).then(function(obj) {
            if (obj.options.protocols[0] === 'rtmp') {
                obj.options.protocols.splice(0, 1); }
            obj.play();
            document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle('fa-pause');
            sound = obj;
            is_playing = true;
        });
    }
}
```

This is working great, but I'm having problems with the play/pause function because, of course, until the song isn't finished `sound===false` it will always play/stop the current track even if I clicked on another div. Here's the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wBZyX/28/) to better understand the behaviour.

Also, I saw the documentation of SC API but I don't understand how to access to the info of the streamed track (title, duration, artwork...)

EDIT:

I came up with a solution, retrieving the current streaming track with:

```
SC.get(url).then(function(data){
  oldid = data.id;
});
```

and then pause it if the old id is equal to the new id.
I still have some problems with the toggle function (toggle only the one that is playing), I'm trying not to use frameworks. This is the [script](http://jsfiddle.net/wBZyX/29/) edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in the code, I've fixed adding a

```
SC.get(url).then(function(data){
  oldid = data.id;
});
```

and then check if `oldid === trackid` like this:

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: 'CLIENT_ID'
});
var oldid;
var is_playing = false,
    sound;
function play(trackid, id){
    var id = id;
    var url = '/tracks/' + trackid;

    if( oldid === trackid) {
        if(is_playing) {
            sound.pause();
            document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle('fa-pause');
            is_playing = false;
        } else {
            sound.play();
            document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle('fa-pause');
            is_playing = true;
        }
    } else {
        SC.stream(url).then(function(obj) {
            if (obj.options.protocols[0] === 'rtmp') {
                obj.options.protocols.splice(0, 1); }
            obj.play();
            document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle('fa-pause');
            sound = obj;
            SC.get(url).then(function(data){
                oldid = data.id;
                        });
            console.log(sound.id);
            is_playing = true;
        });

    }
}
```

Here is the [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wBZyX/29/)